# Can anyone please explain how does this function work?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble figuring out how does this exactly work. Can anyone please explain?

```
def fact(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    return x * fact(x - 1)

x=int(raw_input())
print fact(x)
```

Comment: That's a very simple recursive function, so which part exactly is unclear?

Comment: Google "recursion"

Comment: As posted, it is syntactically invalid.  Please edit your question and indent it correctly.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252728/understanding-factorial-recursion

Answer (score 0):

It gets the factorial of the value x. The value of x is whatever you enter since x = int(raw_input) gets the user input. For example if x=3, then fact(3) will be 3×2=6....